# apple mach-o linker error - string ar

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Xcode builds… I'm following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQCjup8Uv5Q to the T and I'm getting errors.

I have the error apple Mach-o Linker Error some how with
'Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 and it references some items from the location: StringLoadImageMarker in libstringUnityDemo-1.1.3.a (StringAppController.o)
StringSetProjectionAndViewport in libStringUnityDemo-1.1.3a (StringAppController.o)

The undefined symbols to the error above are _timer, _cur0rientation, 0orientationwillchangesuraceextents, _surface, unitykeyboardorientation, handle0rientationRequest, Shouldhandlerotation, present surface, unitysetalloworientationdetection

My software versions are
Unity 4.1.3, Xcode 4.6.2, String 1.1.3

I would appreciate your help!
Regards,

Comment: I guess the libraries which you're using are not supporting to arm7 or some library connections are missing.

Comment: if any of those are `extern`s make sure you've defined the scope as global.

Answer (score 0):

well without doing a logmein or seeing any code... hard to tell... often these linker errors happen when you forget to add the library to the project (not just import the files, but actually go in the project settings and make sure it gets imported, just google importing library to project), or sometimes the libraries you use are ok to use on a device but not on the simulator, or vice versa....